# Auto refresh input field after submit in jquery

Tags: jquery

Does anyone has an idea how to refresh an input field.
My code goes this way.

```
<form>
<?php
$indicode = rand(123456,987654);
$data1 = array(
     'name'        => 'indicode',
     'id'          => 'indicode',
     'value'       => $indicode,
     'type'        => 'hidden'
     );
    echo form_input($data1);
 ?>
</form>

<script>


function submit_member(){

$.post('<?php echo site_url('admin_gcecmem/submit_memberform'); ?>',
     {
        indicode          : $('#indicode').val(),
     },
    function(data){
          if(data.result=='SUCCESS'){
            $('#indicode').val();// i think after a successful submission my indicode should have different value.


            $('#message_success').html(data.message);
              //$('#message_success').show();
              $('#message_success').fadeTo( 1500, 5.0, function(){
                $('#message_success').fadeOut(3000);
              });

          }else{
             $('#message_error').html(data.message);
              //$('#message_error').show();
              $('#message_error').fadeTo( 1500, 5.0, function(){
                $('#message_error').fadeOut(3000);
              });
          }

    },'json'
     );
</script>
```

I want that the indicode will automatically change it's value after a successful saving.

```
ex. 1st Value is indicode = 982348; 
after saving the 2nd Value: indicode = 234234... 
etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

Define this range in `$indicode = rand(123456,987654);` in your submit form(`dmin_gcecmem/submit_memberform`), and add the `$indicode` value in your returned json data with any variable that you want.

for example: `{'result':'SUCCESS', 'indicode': '8974645....'}`

Now in your javascript do a little trick,

```
// On Success
if(data.result=='SUCCESS'){ 
    $('#indicode').val(data.indicode);
.............
}
```

Thats it..

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I try as you said but the 2nd and 3rd value is 0.

Comment: can you show me the code of `admin_gcecmem/submit_memberform` and returned json data?

Comment: problem solved sir. I used the store procedure to create the random number for indicode. anyway, thanks for the help and concern.